# Xtext enum value setting

Tags: enums, xtext

I have an ecore metamodel like this

```
Pattern
  direction:Direction
  patternDetail:Details

Direction
  BOTH=0
  LEFT=1
  RIGHT=2
```

This is a simplification but it is a representation of a graph query language that use patterns. A pattern as a direction and some details (name, whatever)

In my grammar I want to parse some input where the direction information is on 2 places, for example

```
<-[patterndetails]-> (direction = BOTH)
-[patterndetails]->  (direction = RIGHT)
<-[patterndetails]-  (direction = LEFT)
```

So I have created this rule

```
Pattern returns Pattern:
    '<-'patternDetails=PatternDetails'->'
    |'<-'patternDetails=PatternDetails'-'
    |'-'patternDetails=PatternDetails'->'
    ;
```

But I can't figure out how I can set the direction associated.
I try to add `direction=Direction.BOTH` at the end of the first line but it is not possible.
This seems strange because it is possible to affect a value for an EString attribute for example, but not for enums.

Am I missing something on enum access or am I doing this wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have multiple Rules for the same Enum

```
Pattern returns Pattern:
    '<-' patternDetails=PatternDetails direction=Both
    | '<-' patternDetails=PatternDetails direction=Left
    | '-' patternDetails=PatternDetails direction=Right;

enum Direction:
    BOTH |
    LEFT |
    RIGHT;

enum Both returns Direction:
    BOTH='->';

enum Right returns Direction:
    RIGHT='->';

enum Left returns Direction:
    LEFT='-';
```